Public Maven Repository for Realm 6.0.2
Anyone know of a public manven repository where i can find io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2 and io.realm:realm-android-library:6.0.2?
I have a legacy project i need to build.
I tried building realm-java from source but im having problems with cmake/ndk

If you don't manage to build it yourself you have to upgrade to the oldest version available on Maven Central which is 10.4.0. you can see all versions that were once available here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.realm/realm-gradle-plugin just klick on the Jar link and you will see if the artifact still exists.

Found a good maven repo that has old realm versions here: https://mirrors.huaweicloud.com/repository/maven/
